# Android AT commands - Issue with connection

Tags: android, at-command, cellular-network, network-interface

My device is Asus transformer with 3G. I send AT-commands to `/dev/ttyACM0` to turn on the data connection.

In logcat I see that the provider gives me IP, DNS and default gateway addresses. Then I bring up the network interface rmnet0 and assign ip address and gw.

I then run `ping`, but didn't receive any response from the default gw or `8.8.8.8`.

What I have to do more for establishing data connection?

> My AT commands:

```
>AT+CGACT=0,1    
>AT+XDATACHANNEL=1,1,"/USBHSI/0","/USBHSI/1",0    
>AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet.beeline.ru"    
>AT+CGQREQ=1    
>AT+CGQMIN=1    
>AT+XGAUTH=1,1,"beeline","beeline"    
>AT+XDNS=1,1    
>AT+CGACT=1,1    
>AT+CGDCONT?    
>AT+XDNS?    
>AT+CGDATA="M-RAW_IP",1    
>AT+CGACT?    
>AT+COPS=3,0;+COPS?
```

When I do "ip a" after **my** manipulations, I get:

> rmnet0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
>    link/ether 22:a1:04:21:c7:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>    **inet 10.227.30.109/30 brd 10.227.30.111** scope global rmnet0
>    inet6 fe80::20a1:4ff:fe21:c7a8/64 scope link
>       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

When I do "ip a" after turning on the data connection via java android, I get:

> rmnet0:  mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 1000
>       link/ether 22:a1:04:21:c7:a8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>     **inet 10.195.176.206 peer 10.195.176.205/30 brd 10.195.176.207** scope global rmnet0
>     inet6 fe80::20a1:4ff:fe21:c7a8/64 scope link
>        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

What does **peer** mean??

Comment: From your description, it sounds as though you did everything right.  If it's not yet solved, can you post the AT commands + the logcat output + rmnet call and response + ping output from 8.8.8.8?

Comment: There is a similar problem here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/41718-17-help-connect-ping-dhcp Suggested solutions are (1) a firewall blocking access and (2) MacAfee.  What I found interesting was this "Pretty much if ARP works but ping does not then it is a firewall blocking it"

Comment: It was also suggested to re-set the TCP/IP stack (that was for a Windows machine)

Comment: I did not install firewall on my device.. Do you think iptables can block it? But in iptables all accept.

Comment: I think your AT commands are correct, and this question probably should be on SuperUser, because there are more IP network experts there. Can you move the question to http://superuser.com/ ?  Super User is also a Stack Exchange site.

Comment: Another related question from another Stack Exchange site:http://serverfault.com/questions/190121/pcs-using-certain-ip-addresses-cannot-ping-out

Comment: May be I have to do something whith pppd, no? I think something is missing in my actions, but not in firewall or android

Comment: I'm currently trying to solve a very similar problem for a customer. I have been told "the network is not configured correctly" but this is far too vague. So now I'm looking on the internet to try to find out what that means. At the moment, I think your actions are OK, and the problem lies somewhere on the network side.

Comment: PPP is a lower level protocol than IP.  So if you have got DHCP working, and you've got an IP, DNS and Default gateway address, then surely PPP must be working OK.

Comment: please see my question on Super User, which I think is a better place for this problem than SO.http://superuser.com/questions/562254/connected-via-umts-but-cant-ping-default-gateway

Comment: oh, realy interesting why!